# How to create custom layout for widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to create a custom widget in QT that looks something like this:
[image]

The red squares will be displaying an image/icon.
How can I achieve this layout through coding the widget? I will need to create many of those widgets with the same layout but different values in their labels. Ideally, I will display those widgets as a list with a scrollbar in my mainwindow. But right now I'm struggling to just create the layout for those widgets through code. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split you design on to separate segments. Each segment can be either a separate sub layout or a widget. In you example, I see the following segments:

- Large red icon,
- Two labels: TextLabel and 06-November-2014...
- Two labels make a vertical box layout,
- Vertical box layout and large red icon make a horizontal box layout,
- Small red rectangle makes a separate layout,
- All layouts make a main layout.

Now lets code this composition:

```
QLabel *largeRed = new QLabel(this); // Should set an image for this label
QLabel *lbl1 = new QLabel("06-November-2014...", this);
QLabel *lbl2 = new QLabel("TextLabel", this);

QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
vLayout->addWidget(lbl1);
vLayout->addWidget(lbl2);
vLayout->addStretch();

QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
hLayout->addWidget(largeRed);
hLayout->addLayout(vLayout);

QLabel *smallRed = new QLabel(this); // Should set an image for this label
QHBoxLayout *hLayout2 = new QHBoxLayout;
hLayout2->addWidget(smallRed, 0, Qt::AlignRight);

QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
mainLayout->addLayout(hLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(hLayout2);
[..]
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it requires to spend much time, and this time should not be omitted. It doesn't matter that I was a little faster, because all this time you format your code to do it better.

Comment: Thanks! this made things much clearer. I just have one issue with this code. How would I change the spacing between lbl1 and lbl2. Right now there is too much of a space between those two labels.

Comment: @testus, add `vLayout->addStretch();` call for the vLayout. Please check out the updated sample in my answer. It will keep two labels together.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
QPixmap big(75,65);
big.fill(Qt::red);
QPixmap small(25,15);

QVBoxLayout *box = new QVBoxLayout;

QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QLabel *bigLab = new QLabel;
QLabel *smallLab = new QLabel;
QLabel *textLab = new QLabel("Two");
bigLab->setPixmap(big);
smallLab->setPixmap(small);

QHBoxLayout *hLay = new QHBoxLayout;
hLay->addWidget(bigLab);
hLay->addWidget(textLab);

QHBoxLayout *vLay = new QHBoxLayout;
vLay->addWidget(smallLab,0,Qt::AlignRight);

box->addLayout(hLay);
box->addLayout(vLay);

window->setLayout(box);
window->show();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is:

1. Design the layout with Qt Designer/Creator using rich features of layouting.
2. Set its instances (from code) as the item widget of a list or table widget.

Be careful, If the item count of the list is too large, it will perform very slowly.

P.S. If you really need the layout coded, just use the code generated by Qt designer.